# Why isn't ubuntu installing on my Asus EEEPc 900a?

Tags: boot, asus, bios

I installed ubuntu on my Asus EEEPc 900a **twice** and it doesn't boot.
I even disabled all boot sources except the hard drive in BIOS.

Comment: I just now entered this site & saw your question. May I ask if you figured it out? If not, and are still having issues, are you trying to boot your liveCD from an SD card? & if you are, are you using your SD slot or a card reader?

Answer (score 1):

IF you fail to see the Grub:- Insert a Ubuntu 12.10 Live-CD/DVD and run the following commands:

```
`$sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt` # XY is the drive, eg. sda or sda1

`$sudo chroot /mnt`

`$sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` #X is drive number

`$sudo update-grub`
```

Reboot and take out the LiveDVD.
Lemme know if it doesn't work as intended.